# Preloader CSS works locally but not on server

Tags: html, css

I'm using a Bootstrap template and there is a bit of inline CSS in a partials HTML file for a preloader so that the tables are displayed only after the contents have loaded.

```
   <head>
      <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
      <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
      <link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
      <meta name="msapplication-config" content="browserconfig.xml">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="assets/static/images/favicon.png"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/easy-autocomplete.min.css"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/itsjavi/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css">
      <style>
        #loader{
          transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
          opacity:1;
          visibility:visible;
          position:fixed;
          height:100vh;
          width:100%;
          background:#fff;
          z-index:90000
     }
        #loader.fadeOut{
          opacity:0;
          visibility:hidden
        }
        .spinner{
          width:40px;
          height:40px;
          position:absolute;
          top:calc(50% - 20px);
          left:calc(50% - 20px);
          background-color:#333;
          border-radius:100%;
          -webkit-animation:sk-scaleout 1s infinite ease-in-out;
          animation:sk-scaleout 1s infinite ease-in-out
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes sk-scaleout{
          0%{-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
          100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);
          opacity:0
        }
      }
       @keyframes sk-scaleout{
          0%{-webkit-transform:scale(0);
          transform:scale(0)
          }
          100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);
          transform:scale(1);
          opacity:0
       }
     }
    </style>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="vendor/itsjavi/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "js/validation.js"></script>
      <script src = "js/scripts.js"></script>
   </head>
```

This bit of code works when I try it locally on XAMPP but not when I upload it to the server. Also not sure if this is relevant, but this code is part of a partials file used in another HTML file one directory above. How can I fix this?

Comment: So can you find these styles after the page is fully loaded? How about you inject them manually via devtool in page footer?

Comment: Can we see the html?

Comment: @BrentStees I've edited and added the <head> portion of the HTML.

Comment: @ChrisChen Yes it appears exactly like this in the fully loaded page in the HTML source.

Comment: my suggestion would be please avoid using CDN maybe your server is blocking the  CDN. please download the jquery and linked it locally the same as you have done for `validation.js`

Comment: on server check for error or missing files in inspect

Comment: @HaSnenTai I changed all files from CDN to local, still not fixed.

Comment: @SalunkeAkash The console shows no missing files.

Comment: Will not having https cause any such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with one of the javascript files (vendor.js) that I had modified. I used the stock file that comes with bootstrap and it fixed the issue.